# Show That User Is Logged Into iOS app

Tags: python, ios, flask, flask-login

The login works from the backend and it goes to the home screen after login on iOS. But how do I do guarantee that the user is actually being logged in?

For example, I have a Label that I would like the user's username to be displayed in, but I don't know how to get the user's username .

I have an idea where I can call the server and it will return the username in JSON format, but isn't this kind of inefficient? What is a better way to do this?

PS. I am a first time iOS programmer

Additional info:
I am also currently using Flask and the Flask-Login extension for the backend. Using the login_user(user) method. This has worked in the past for web dev, but how do I get it to work for iOS dev.

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    params = json.loads(request.data)
    username = params['username']
    password = params['password']
    u = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if u:
        if utils.check_password_hash(password, u.pw_hash):
            login_user(u)
            return ('', 200)
        else:
            return ('', 400)
    else:
        return ('', 400)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Before you downvote, please tell me why you downvoted, I don't get it. The question seems fine to me and I am sure it is helpful for future first timers too. Don't be a hater. Be a lover.

Comment: @Jules Mazur, if you read the question you will see that I have implemented login with Flask and I have experiemented with using the server for currentUser but this is inefficient

Comment: Traditionally, StackOverflow questions of this kind include *some* relevant code, in addition to the explanation you already provided.

Comment: There you go Jules, you could have just asked for the code and I would have given it to ya. Ask next time before downvoting. You aren't being nice to new members of the site.

Comment: The site includes a [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), and in this context, asking "what have you tried" generally understands the inclusion of a code sample by the asker. I'm not trying to be mean at all, but the first paragraph of the FAQ can be quoted as saying, "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them." You just have to understand that, as a Q/A site for professionals, there is a reasonably high standard of quality, in order to minimize time wasted trying to clear up ambiguity. Anyhow, welcome, and enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Parse.com's iOS SDK (https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS).  It provides a login form as well as the ability to use a PFUser object to determine if the user is logged in or not.  The best thing about Parse is it's free. :)

Calling `[PFUser currentUser]` will return the user that's logged in or nil if there is no user.

Comment: I will look into it. I'd prefer to do my own backend API though, is there any way to do this with my own API. If there isn't than I will use Parse

Comment: You'll need to develop your own authentication system and a way to communicate with it.  I've done that in the past using a Rails site on the back end.  My own experience is to minimize the time writing code that doesn't directly affect your application and push that onto someone else.  Parse.com does that for me.  In my latest app I've used it instead of my own auth system.